# Add to Regex pattern so string may not contain period

Tags: regex

I am trying to add to an existing regex

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$
```

I would like to disallow any periods by adding to above regex. I don't have a good understanding of regex but need to quickly validate so user can't enter  a period (`.`)

Comment: Your regex matches from 1 -100 and does not allow any periods.

Comment: Right now I can enter 0.9 or any fraction

Comment: With the regex you have you cannot use it for decimals

Comment: [`^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$`](https://regex101.com/r/Phb7UE/1) does not match 0.9 Can you share the code in your question?

Comment: Use `type="text"` with `pattern="[1-9][0-9]?|100"`

Answer (score 0):

This Regex will only allow numbers 0-9 and nothing more ^[0-9]*$ and if you want to not be able to start with 0 then use following ^(?!0+$)[0-9]{1,100}$ with maximum of 100 digits. You can modify max amount inside curly brackets.

Comment: This allows for text starting with 0.. while the original regex disallows it.